# What's Apple's Guideline on when to use modal vs pushed view controller?

Tags: ios, user-interface, modalviewcontroller, hig

Apple's guideline on when to use modal vs pushed view controller upon tapping a table view cell seems confusing.

Take Settings->Twitter for example. If you tap Add Account cell, the view is pushed in for you to sign in. If you click on an existing Account, a modal view is shown instead.  In most other places in Settings, pushed view is used instead.  In Contacts' Edit mode, modal is used instead.  I can't find a common pattern on when to use which.

What's Apple's Guideline on when to use modal vs pushed view controller when tapping a table view cell?

Comment: That's a really good question, actually. The biggest rhyme-or-reason I've seen between them is that a pushed view is more likely to be thrown away by non-standard means, whereas a modal view only has developer-defined ways of exiting (so you're less likely to piss them off when their changes aren't saved because they pressed 'back' instead of 'done')

Comment: @iAdjunct Great reason provided.